# Is there a native way of defining a directory chooser in android API 17+?

Tags: android

Is there a native way of defining a directory chooser in android API 17+ ?
I'm finding references to all kind of libraries for this but, I'm not able to find any native implementation.
Thanks

Comment: No directory chooser but a file chooser: ACTION_PICK.

Comment: I know about the file chooser, but I'm looking for a dir chooser.

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE since Lollipop.

Comment: For whoever will be interested, I've found this implementation : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/547636/Android-Ready-to-use-simple-directory-chooser-dial